# Adding mail configuration in service provider not working in laravel 7.0 it gives Unsupported mail transport Error

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am working in Laravel and have added the mail configuration in the "MailConfigServiceProvider" but it's giving error.
I am currently using Laravel 7.0.
Is there anything missing in the configuration or I have taken a wrong approach?

Here is the error

**Error**

```
InvalidArgumentException
Unsupported mail transport [1].
```

Here is my mail service provider code:

```
public function boot()
{
    $emailServices = EmailServices::where(['active' => 1])->latest()->first();

    if ($emailServices) {
        $config = array(
            'driver'     => $emailServices->driver,
            'host'       => $emailServices->host,
            'port'       => $emailServices->port,
            'username'   => $emailServices->username,
            'password'   => $emailServices->password,
            'encryption' => null,
            'from'       => array('address' => 'codingdriver15@gmail.com', 'name' => $emailServices->name),
            'sendmail'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
            'pretend'    => false,
        );

        Config::set('mail', $config);
    }
}
```

I have also added the provider in the `config/add.php` file

```
'providers' => [
    App\Providers\MailConfigServiceProvider::class,
],
```

I am known to the `.env` file approach but here I am trying to make it dynamic.
Any help or suggestion will be helpful and appreciated.

```
MAIL_DRIVER: SMTP
MAIL_ENCRYPTION: TLS
PORT:2525
```

Comment: Can you provide what the emailServices->property are on the runtime? Of course omit username and password

Comment: @TZiebura the mail properly working proerly i have check them adding in the .env file and mail is working find, issue is just that i want to make it dynamic and this above provider gives error.

Comment: @TZiebura updated some details in the question's bottom.

Comment: if your configuration works when you put it in the .env file it could mean that the mailer configuration is not applied from your EmailService but still reads from the .env the only valid solution I could think of is to make some sort of a wrapper around the mailer service. I'd check how exactly the mailer is instantiated and how the config is loaded and then created my own Mailer class instantiating the actual mailer with your config either from array or a configuration class/entity